# How can I add an item into the ViewBag from within a class that inherits ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service?

Tags: razor, service, servicestack

Is access to the ViewBag possible with ServiceStack.Razor?

Comment: I was able to get around my issue by declaratively setting some attributes in my views (via the ViewBag) and then using them in the Layout.  I'm still curious if the ViewBag can be accessed from a service though...